# Change current database path in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am currently working with a SQL Server database. I want to change the database path from its default position to other through a query.

Is it possible to do it without creating new database ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

hello raj for change database path you need permission for that directory and after that execute below script in sql server

```
ALTER DATABASE LinkedIndb SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;
ALTER DATABASE LinkedIndb SET ONLINE;

ALTER DATABASE LinkedIndb MODIFY FILE 
(
   Name = LinkedIndb,
   Filename = 'D:\DATA\LinkedIndb.MDF'
);

ALTER DATABASE LinkedIndb MODIFY FILE 
(
   Name = LinkedIndb_log, 
   Filename = 'D:\DATA\LinkedIndb_log.LDF'
);

ALTER DATABASE LinkedIndb SET ONLINE;
ALTER DATABASE LinkedIndb SET MULTI_USER;
```

Comment: Thanks hardik, was looking for this only. thank you verry much it really works for me